# How to show SVN diffs matching a regex pattern

Tags: svn, diff

I want to see the changes in my repository, but only the chunks that contain comments (in c++ that'd be lines starting by // or enclosed in /**/ )

Answer (score 1):

Subversion does not provide any built-in tool for full-text code search. You should write a script that will process diffs or use tools that provide full-text search capabilities for SVN repositories.